# Отправка с https на http ajax

Tags: javascript, консоль, браузер

Хочу в консоли отладки отправить ajax с https сайта на http. http - мой, аякс с других доменов открыт.

Знаю, что браузеры такие вещи блокируют, но может быть, известно какое-нибудь расширение, или способ обхода, чтобы это выполнить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена. Все решается разрешением в браузере смешанного контента. @Lefree и @Pavel Mayorov - советы так - же работают.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать свой https. Если вам для собственного использования ("в консоли отладки") - то сертификат можно брать вообще самоподписанный.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  в документации .ajax() по jQuery там есть параметр `crossDomain`

Comment: Спасибо, но это уже пробовалось. К сожалению, не помогает

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов тогда больше деталей что и как пытаетесь делать. Вообще в принципе браузер не даст вам такое вытворять) но классический прием это прокся, то есть домен А должен обращаться к разным доменам B и C. Тогда на домене А делают скриптик на сервере которые принимает запросы, отправляет на другие домены и возвращает обратно ответ, как будто все происходит в рамках одного домена. Уловили мысль?

Comment: Что бы было понятно, приведу пример. Есть сайт на https, в котором есть форма с вопросами и ответами. И есть api, которое позволяет отвечать на эти вопросы, но подключиться к нему можно только через curl. Подключение я забил в php файл на openserver с открытым доступом по ajax, и через ajax в консоли отладки с сайта с формой к нему обращаюсь, ответами заполняю форму. Так вот, если сайт с формой http - все нормально работает. Но если сайт с формой https - браузер блокирует запрос к моему openserver-сайту, потому что он http. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов добавил новый ответ так как этот не влезал в комментарий

Answer (score -1):

@Юрий_Смирнов Ну я правильно понял. Это я вам предлагал классическое решение. А конкретно с вашей проблемой как вы описали, ajax правильно себя ведет, потому что вы нарушаете CORS и SOP одновременно. Если вы добавили в заголовки сервера Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.site.com тогда CORS не нарушаете. Остается SOP , а его вы НИКАК не обойдете. Поэтому повторюсь ДВАЖДЫ, делаете на этом же домене скрипт проксю в ТОМ ЖЕ протоколе, чтобы HTTPS -> HTTPS (Proxy php script) обращался а уже HTTPS (Proxy php script) -> куда угодно на любой домен и порт.
Итого HTTPS Domen A -> HTTPS (Proxy php script) Domen A -> HTTP Domen B

Comment: Так первый домен с формой, который https - не мой. Все что я могу делать - вызывать на нем скрипты в консоли отладочной, и все. Мой домен только http с php скриптом.

Comment: Что значит "SOP вы никак не обойдете"? Заголовки CORS перекрывают SOP. Просто потому что CORS - это более новая технология, созданная специально для устранения недостатков старой SOP. Та вещь, на которую натолкнулся автор, называется не SOP, а "mixed content blocking". Еще сюда могла вмешаться CSP.

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов если будешь вызывать таким образом скрипты только из своего браузера с консолью, просто отключи в нем безопасность и все, можешь посылать что угодно и куда угодно

Comment: @PavelMayorov то есть автор НЕ нарушает SOP делая из https к http запрос ? Очень хочу почитать ваш ответ...

Comment: @Lerfee, И как отключить именно mixed content blocking? Разве есть такая возможность у браузера? По - моему, он автоматически это дело блокирует.

Comment: @Lerfee нарушает. Но SOP никак не влияет на XHR-запросы.

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов

How to disable Same Origin Policy in:

1) Firefox:
about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false

2) Chrome:
run with command line switch: --disable-web-security

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов Привел примеры, но они старые, не факт что что-то изменилось. Какой браузер и какая версия?